# How do I locally merge a remotely merged commit from branch to mainline?

Tags: git

1. I cloned the remote repo

```
Git Tree(local)                         Git Tree(remote)

A - B - C - D                           A - B - C - D
```

2. Created a new commit E

```
Git Tree(local)                         Git Tree(remote)

A - B - C - D - E                       A - B - C - D
```

3. Raised PR for commit E (not yet merged in remote)

```
Git Tree(local)                         Git Tree(remote)

A - B - C - D - E                       A - B - C - D
```

4. Created a new branch from D (current head in remote)

```
Git Tree(local)                         Git Tree(remote)

A - B - C - D - E                       A - B - C - D
             \
              new_branch
```

5. Created a commit F in new branch

```
Git Tree(local)                         Git Tree(remote)

A - B - C - D - E                       A - B - C - D
             \
              F
```

6. Raised PR for commit F (merged in remote mainline)

```
Git Tree(local)                         Git Tree(remote)

A - B - C - D - E                       A - B - C - D - F
             \
              F
```

How do I merge the commit F to the mainline in my local so my tree looks like this?

```
Git Tree(local)

A - B - C - D - F - E
```

Comment: you're looking for `git rebase`.  Rebasing rewrites git history so it's best to do it on a disposable branch first until you're happy with the results.  Just locally checkout `main` (or whatever branch with `E`), then `git fetch`, `git checkout -b rebase` , `git rebase  origin/main` and your `rebase` should result in the desired local history.

Comment: In particular, after you have rebased your commit, this *invalidates* your earlier PR, because it still references the old E, but I suspect that you prefer that your new E to be used in the PR.

Comment: I do not want to invalidate the earlier PR. If the PR is merged with the mainline will the remote tree be like `A - B - C - D - F - E`? If so, after merging the PR I can delete my local repo and clone fresh repo from remote again?

Answer (score 0):

so if you are on a branch of commit E and your git tree looks like

```
Git Tree(local)                         Git Tree(remote)

A - B - C - D - E                       A - B - C - D - F
             \
              F
```

then you could do a pull rebase of your remote branch so something like

```
git pull --rebase origin main
```

of course your remote could be named different then "origin" and the remote branch could be a different one then "main". and this remote main should be a branch which has assigned commit F and looks like the "Git remote (tree)" structure in the "diagram" above.

in the end this will do a fetch of the remote branch. and then rebased the remote branch with your current state.

in the end you will come up with

```
Git history of your current branch after pull rebase

A - B - C - D - F - E
```

of course you know have "changed history" and if some other user is working on the same branch and you force push it, it will cause trouble.

just as a side node, the real tree contains everything (also the state before rebase and so on). git is using a immutable data structure so nothing really has changed. you just have now a new structure which is assigned to your branch (sure git will clean up unresolveable references from time to time (depending on settings but i'm pretty sure it's the case with default settings))